# Why ranking is incorrect when join more than two tables?

Tags: mysql

I learn how to create the ranking from the website(http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group)

but I don't know why my ranking becomes 1 when I join more than 2 tables.

For example, code below works great but when I uncomment the lines, it doesn't work anymore.
any idea why?

As well as, select only <= 3 doesn't work neither when I subquery the correct one.

````
SELECT 
        c.clientname                ,
        worklist.clientreference    ,
        worklist.workordernumber    ,
        worklist.workordertype      ,
        worklist.approveddate       ,
        worklist.taskid             ,
     -- p.vacant     
     -- p.autosecure                AS "Auto Secure",
        @num:=IF(@grp = worklist.clientreference, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
        @grp:=worklist.clientreference AS dummy
                        
FROM
        worklist
        LEFT JOIN client c      ON worklist.clientid = c.clientid
    -- LEFT JOIN property p     ON worklist.propertyid = p.propertyid
    -- LEFT JOIN investor i     ON i.investorid = worklist.investorid
WHERE
        worklist.status IN ('crteria')
        AND c.clientname IN ('crteria')
        AND worklist.workorder = "crteria"
    -- AND p.status = 'crteria'
    -- AND p.vacant NOT REGEXP "crteria"
        
ORDER BY worklist.clientreference DESC```
````

Comment: User-defined variables are processed with definite rows order only when single row source is used. So enumerate `worklist` only (all columns in the expressions which both uses UDV and defines the sorting belongs to this table) in subquery then join another tables in outer query. Or backward - join all tables in subquery then apply UDV calculations in outer query.

Comment: ok. didn't know that! I'll give it a shot. no wonder it disappear all the time.